# Super is always pressed down after a mysterious shortcut is pressed

Tags: shortcut-keys

About once every 1-2 months, I accidentally press some mysterious shortcut, possibly from some combination of fn+alt+super keys, where the result is that the super key is constantly applied. E.g. pressing the arrow buttons moves the windows to different spots on the screen, pressing tab brings up the switch between apps menu, and pressing d displays the desktop.

This happens just randomly as I'm typing away where I accidentally input the wrong shortcut and now my super key is constantly applied.

Do you know how to unapply the super key? And what this shortcut may be so that I can disable it?

All I can do to turn it off is restart my computer when this happens